# Renaming a class object and a windows service object in VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-services

Folks, my project scope / requirements were modified in the middle of development (never happened before)...

so my issue right now is that I need to rename my class object which is currently named **EmployerWorkflowService** to **EmployerWorkflow**

because a new windows service object will be created that will be named "**EmployerWorkflowService**"

I am using VS 2010, C#. There is only one solution file that contains both these projects.

Any suggestions on how to rename the class object as painlessly as possible and have the whole solution file compile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click on class name in Visual Studio, select **Refactor** > **Rename...** and Visual Studio will update all references for you.
As a shortcut, you can press <kbd>F2</kbd> when caret is on the class name, or use a smart tag that appears when you edit the name manually.